# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: FormasPagos (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling:

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, data

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar una aplicacion correctamente. La misma ejecuta pero al querer abrir una funcion de la misma me tira este error:
Todo es con java. Si alguien supiera solucionarlo me vendria de mucha ayuda, ya que estoy hace semanas con lo mismo y no encuentro el error. Supongo que es por algo de la data pero no estoy seguro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuacion mi codigo.

Main activity:

```
    package com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.views.main;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.TextAppearanceSpan;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.R;
import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.component.searchtoolbar.SearchToolbar;
import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.repositories.LoginRepository;
import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.utils.PreferencesMethods;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.views.login.LoginActivity;
import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.views.UpdateActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

private FloatingActionButton cartFAB;

MaterialToolbar toolbar;
private ToolbarHelper toolbarHelper;
AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
private CollapsingToolbarHelper collapsingToolbarHelper;
private SearchViewHelper searchViewHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerReceiver(RECEIVER_CLOSE, new IntentFilter("close"));
    registerReceiver(RECEIVER_UPDATE, new IntentFilter("update"));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_articulos);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbarHelper = new ToolbarHelper(this, toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    collapsingToolbarHelper = new CollapsingToolbarHelper(this, appBarLayout);
    collapsingToolbarHelper.configure();
    collapsingToolbarHelper.getTxtCliente().setOnClickListener(
            v -> goTo(R.id.action_to_listasDePreciosFragment)
        );

    cartFAB = findViewById(R.id.button_ver_pedidos);

    searchViewHelper = new SearchViewHelper(this,appBarLayout);

    initNavigationDrawer();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
            new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    SearchToolbar searchToolbar = findViewById(R.id.search_toolbar);
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
        if(destination.getId() == R.id.ArticulosFragment){
            collapsingToolbarHelper.setExpanded(true, true);
            cartFAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.action_articulos);
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            toggle.syncState();
            toolbarHelper.configureToolbar();
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));
        }else{
            if(searchToolbar.isOpen()) searchToolbar.close();
            cartFAB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            collapsingToolbarHelper.setExpanded(false,true);
            drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
        }
    });
}

public CollapsingToolbarHelper getCollapsingToolbarHelper() {
    return collapsingToolbarHelper;
}

public SearchViewHelper getSearchViewHelper() {
    return searchViewHelper;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); return;
    }
    if(collapsingToolbarHelper.isOpenDrawerLayoutFilter()){
        collapsingToolbarHelper.closeDrawerLayoutFilter(); return;
    }

    NavController navController =
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    if( navController.getCurrentDestination().getId() == R.id.ArticulosFragment) {
        showDialogSalir();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void showDialogSalir(){
    SpannableString spanTitle = new SpannableString("Cerrar");
    spanTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary)),
            0, spanTitle.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    );

    String msg = "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?";

    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setTitle(spanTitle)
            .setMessage(msg).setPositiveButton(
            "Aceptar", (dialog, which) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                super.onBackPressed();
            }).setNeutralButton("Cancelar", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss()).show();
}
@Override
@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId){
        case R.id.action_create_objeto_facturable:
            goTo(R.id.action_to_CreateObjectoFacturableFragment);break;
        case R.id.action_pendientes:
            goTo(R.id.action_to_pedidosPendientesFragment);break;
        case R.id.action_enviados:
            goTo(R.id.action_to_pedidosApiFragment);break;
        case R.id.action_listaDePrecios:
            goTo(R.id.action_to_listasDePreciosFragment);break;
        case R.id.action_clientes_sin_alta:
            goTo(R.id.action_to_ClientesSinAltaFragment);break;
        case R.id.action_log_out:
            this.logOut();break;
        default:break;
    }
    return false;
}
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;
    onCreate(db);
}

private void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

private void logOut() {
    LoginRepository.getInstance().logOut(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void goTo(int fragment){
    Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(fragment);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

public void initNavigationDrawer(){
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.articulos_nav_view);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    initMenuStyles(navigationView.getMenu());

    TextView username = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textview_username);
    String usernameString = PreferencesMethods.getUsername(this) + "!";
    username.setText(usernameString);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void initMenuStyles(Menu menu) {
    int itemCategoryColor = R.style.item_category_color;
    setStyleCategory(R.id.cuenta_menu_category, itemCategoryColor, menu);
    setStyleCategory(R.id.listas_menu_category, itemCategoryColor, menu);
    setStyleCategory(R.id.pedido_menu_category, itemCategoryColor, menu);
    setStyleCategory(R.id.action_articulos, R.style.item_category_rounded,menu);
}

private void setStyleCategory(int category,int style, Menu menu){
    MenuItem tools= menu.findItem(category);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(tools.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, style), 0, s.length(), 0);
    tools.setTitle(s);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver RECEIVER_CLOSE = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = "Se ha cerrado la sesión";

        if(intent.getStringExtra("message_close") != null){
            message = intent.getStringExtra("message_close");
        }

        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder messageDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
                .setTitle("Sesión Finalizada")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Cerrar", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        messageDialog.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> finish());
        messageDialog.show();
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver RECEIVER_UPDATE = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){goToUpdateActivity();}
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try{
    unregisterReceiver(RECEIVER_UPDATE);
    }catch (Exception ignored){}
    unregisterReceiver(RECEIVER_CLOSE);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(RECEIVER_UPDATE);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(RECEIVER_UPDATE, new IntentFilter("update"));
}

private void goToUpdateActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, UpdateActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    this.finishAffinity();
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

DataBase.java:

```
    package SQLite;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos.utils.PreferencesMethods;

import java.io.File;

import SQLite.articulos.ArticulosDaoImpl;
import SQLite.clientespendientes.ClientesPendientesDaoImpl;
import SQLite.clientespendientes.models.ClientesPendientes;
import SQLite.dao.ArticulosDao;
import SQLite.dao.ClientesPendientesDao;
import SQLite.dao.FacturadorDao;
import SQLite.dao.FilterDao;
import SQLite.dao.OtrosFacturablesDao;
import SQLite.dao.PedidosAPIDao;
import SQLite.dao.PedidosDao;
import SQLite.dao.PedidosPendientesDao;
import SQLite.dao.PreciosDao;
import SQLite.facturador.FacturadorDaoImpl;
import SQLite.otrosfacturables.OtrosFacturablesDaoImpl;
import SQLite.otrosfacturables.models.OtrosFacturables;
import SQLite.pedidos.PedidosDaoImpl;
import SQLite.pedidos.models.Pedidos;
import SQLite.pedidosapi.PedidosAPIDaoImpl;
import SQLite.pedidosapi.models.PedidosAPI;
import SQLite.pedidosapi.models.PedidosArticulosAPI;
import SQLite.pedidospendientes.PedidosPendientesDaoImpl;
import SQLite.pedidospendientes.models.PedidosArticulosPendiente;
import SQLite.pedidospendientes.models.PedidosPendientes;
import SQLite.precios.PreciosDaoImpl;
import SQLite.objectfilter.FilterDaoImpl;

public class DataBase {




    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static DataBase db;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Articulos_";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    private SQLiteDatabase db_sqlite;
    public ConexionHelper conexionHelper;
    private final DbContentProvider dbContentProvider;

    public FilterDao filterDao;
    public ArticulosDao articulosDao;
    public PreciosDao preciosDao;
    public FacturadorDao facturadorDao;
    public PedidosDao pedidosDao;
    public PedidosAPIDao pedidosAPIDao;
    public PedidosPendientesDao pedidosPendientesDao;
    public OtrosFacturablesDao otrosFacturablesDao;
    public ClientesPendientesDao clientesPendientesDao;


    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

    private DataBase(Context context) {
        String version = PreferencesMethods.getNroActualizacion(context);
        conexionHelper = new ConexionHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME+version,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db_sqlite = conexionHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbContentProvider = DbContentProvider.getInstance(db_sqlite);
        filterDao = new FilterDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        articulosDao = new ArticulosDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        preciosDao = new PreciosDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        facturadorDao = new FacturadorDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        pedidosDao = new PedidosDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        pedidosAPIDao = new PedidosAPIDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        pedidosPendientesDao = new PedidosPendientesDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        otrosFacturablesDao = new OtrosFacturablesDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        clientesPendientesDao = new ClientesPendientesDaoImpl(dbContentProvider);
        createNeededTables();
    }

    public static DataBase getInstance(Context context){
        if(!checkDataBase(context)){
            return null;
        }
        if(db == null){
            db = new DataBase(context);
        }
        return db;
    }

    public static boolean checkDataBase(Context context){
//        if(context == null) return false;
        String version = PreferencesMethods.getNroActualizacion(context);
        String pathname = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir +"/databases/" +("Articulos_"+version);
        File databaseFile = new File(pathname);
        return databaseFile.exists();
    }

    public static void restart(Context context) {
        if(db == null) return;
        String version = PreferencesMethods.getNroActualizacion(context);
        db.conexionHelper = new ConexionHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME+version,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db.db_sqlite = db.conexionHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.dbContentProvider.setSqliteDb(db.db_sqlite);
        db.createNeededTables();
    }

    public void createNeededTables(){
        createIfNoExistTablesPedidos();
        createIfNoExistTablesPedidosAPI();
        createIfNoExistTablesPedidosArticulosAPI();
        createIfNoExistTablesPedidosPendientes();
        createIfNoExistTablesPedidosArticulosPendientes();
        createIfNoExistTablesOtrosFacturables();
        createIfNoExistTablesClientesPendientes();
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesClientesPendientes() {
        db_sqlite.execSQL(ClientesPendientes.Schema.CLIENTESPENDIENTES_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesPedidos(){
        db_sqlite.execSQL(Pedidos.Schema.PEDIDOS_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesPedidosAPI() {
        db_sqlite.execSQL(PedidosAPI.Schema.PEDIDOSAPI_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesPedidosArticulosAPI() {
        db_sqlite.execSQL(PedidosArticulosAPI.Schema.PEDIDOSARTICULOSAPI_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesPedidosPendientes() {
        db_sqlite.execSQL(PedidosPendientes.Schema.PEDIDOSPENDIENTES_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesPedidosArticulosPendientes() {
        db_sqlite.execSQL(PedidosArticulosPendiente.Schema.PEDIDOSARTICULOSPENDIENTE_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    private void createIfNoExistTablesOtrosFacturables() {
        db_sqlite.execSQL(OtrosFacturables.Schema.OTROSFACTURABLES_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    public void changeDataBase(Context context) {
        String version = PreferencesMethods.getNroActualizacion(context);
        conexionHelper = new ConexionHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME+version,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db_sqlite = conexionHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbContentProvider.setSqliteDb(db_sqlite);
        createNeededTables();
    }



    public void close() {
        db = null;
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paradigma.SIGEPedidos"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 20
        versionName "1.20.0-alpha"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]


            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    ext {
        appCompatVersion = '1.3.0-rc01'

    }
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':EmptyMessageLayout')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.1.0'




    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.2'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'



    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db-encrypt:1.0.6'

    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.paradigma.components:components:1.0.0'

    def archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
//Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"




}
```

Codigo que no puede cargar (FormasPago.java):

```
    package SQLite.facturador.models;

import android.database.Cursor;

import com.paradigma.components.MultiSelectInterface;

public class FormasPagos implements MultiSelectInterface {

    public String codigo;

    public String nombre;

    public boolean deBaja;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return Long.valueOf(codigo);
    }

    @Override
    public String displayName() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public interface Schema{
        String FORMASPAGO_TABLE = "FormasPagos";
        String COLUMN_CODIGO = "codigo";
        String COLUMN_NOMBRE = "nombre";
        String COLUMN_DEBAJA = "deBaja";
        String[] FORMASPAGO_COLUMNS = new String[] {
                COLUMN_CODIGO, COLUMN_NOMBRE, COLUMN_DEBAJA,
        };
    }

    public void setFormasPagosValues(Cursor cursor, String prefix) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getColumnIndex(prefix + Schema.COLUMN_CODIGO) != -1) {
                int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(prefix + Schema.COLUMN_CODIGO);
                this.codigo = cursor.getString(idIndex);
            }

            if (cursor.getColumnIndex(prefix + Schema.COLUMN_NOMBRE) != -1) {
                int nombreIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(prefix + Schema.COLUMN_NOMBRE);
                this.nombre = cursor.getString(nombreIndex);
            }

            if (cursor.getColumnIndex(prefix + Schema.COLUMN_DEBAJA) != -1) {
                int debajaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(prefix + Schema.COLUMN_DEBAJA);
                this.deBaja = Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(debajaIndex));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Espero una respuesta para solucionar el error, muchas gracias.

***Si se necesita mostrar mas codigo diganme que.***

Comment: El problema es que la tabla no existe, ¿Probaste reinstalando tu aplicativo o cambiando la versión de la base de datos? Recuerda que para cada cosa nueva que quieras agregar, debes utilizar el onUpgrade

Comment: Hola, buenos días. Gracias por la respuesta @FranqoBalsamo , con respecto a lo que me decís, si, ya probé cambiando la versión de la base de datos aumentándola y sigue pasando. Con respecto a reinstalar el aplicativo, te referís a reinstalar android studio? Me parecía que había un problema con la tabla. No sabría como solucionarlo, porque en realidad tendría que estar en el mismo código. Gracias y espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Voy a cambiar mi respuesta después de leer tu código, ¿Dónde creas la Tabla? Veo que tienes creada la clase FormasPagos.java, pero no veo que lo llames en ningún lado. Si voy a tu DataBase.java: no veo que llames en ningún momento a tu FormasPago.